# Is this method a proper way to avoid .map is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm loading an array of objects via an API. In my render I'm mapping over the array to populate a picker. As the API request takes a second or two I get ".map is not a function." errors.  If I just wrap that in an if statement and check the length of the array I can avoid the error. Is this a "react" way or is there a better way of doing this?

Constructor:

```
this.state = {forumObject: []}
```

Component did mount:

```
        axios.get(CONFIG.API_URL+`/my-api/v1/forums/forum` )
         .then(res => {
           if (res && res.data) {
             this.setState({
                  forumObject: res.data
             });
           }
         })
```

Inside my render:

```
   var forum = this.state.forumObject;

   var pickList = '';

   if(forum.length > 0){
        pickList = forum.map( ( {title, id} ) => {
          return <Picker.Item key={id} label={title} value={id} />
      })
   }
```

Then in my return I'm doing {pickList}

Comment: When are you setting the value of formObject state ? Can you share that piece of code?

Comment: define your forumObject as empty array,
this.state = {
forumObject:[]
}
So that it will not give .map function error problem when data is not loaded by api

Comment: Because map function needs empty array otherwise it will throw error

Comment: I have updated the question with my constructor and api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, myself and many i know usually do like below

```
{forum.length > 0 ?

     forum.map( ( {title, id} ) => {
          return <Picker.Item key={id} label={title} value={id} />
      })

  :
  null
}
```

Another Alternative is

```
{forum.length > 0 &&

    forum.map( ( {title, id} ) => {
         return <Picker.Item key={id} label={title} value={id} />
    })
}
```

The two solutions are clean neat and the react way i can say. Moreover , forum.length may not be necessary. just `forum` might be enough. like

```
 { forum  && 
     forum.map( ( {title, id} ) => {
             return <Picker.Item key={id} label={title} value={id} />
     })

}
```

The above will work provided forum is either `undefined` or has length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a proper way of rendering values which is undefined or null at first render. If you can set the data in your state to an empty array as told in the comments, this simply solves your problem. But if somehow your data undefined at that time there are multiple ways of doing this.

Using an `if` statement if you want to show something else:

```
render() {
 if ( !forum ) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>
        // or return <SpinnerComponent />
    }
 return ( <div>...</div> );       
 }
```

Or you can use ternary operator:

```
render() {
    return (
        forum ? <div>...</div> : <p>Loading...</p>
    );
}
```

If you don't need to show something else while fetching data:

```
render() {
    return forum && ( <div>...</div> );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React ive sense would be like, state should be a data representation of UI so, intialise the state like,

```
constructor(){

this.state = {
 forumObject:[]
}

...
render(){

   this.state.forumObject.map( ( {title, id} ) => {
          return <Picker.Item key={id} label={title} value={id} />
      })
   }
}
```

So that when ever the api returns, setting the state value at that time will fill the this.state.forum object and there by automaticaly adding the UI with components without the need of any condition checks.

Comment: Rohith where are you setting the variable "forum"? Or did you mean to write this.state.forumObject?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think its answer for the stack overflow community.